# C# memory data store - fixed byte arrays or "safe" byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, byte, unmanaged

I have been trying to optimize the in-memory data store I am writing for my project and have tried to rewrite the storing core and use fixed byte structures, but the performance dropped immensely, so I wanted to ask which approach should I stick to?
This question is related to this one [Optimizing C# large dataset iterations - External code in profiler and weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129284/optimizing-c-sharp-large-dataset-iterations-external-code-in-profiler-and-weir) , where I have multiple dictionaries, each holding exactly 1 million 100 byte long arrays, that have certain structure to hold column data.

There is a "Shard" object, that has these internal storages:

```
    private Dictionary<Guid, int> innerCache;
    private DataBytes[] innerValues;
    private int[] vacancies;
```

Set up in a way, where Guid - Int Dictionary serves for fast Guid lookup and INT Value points to an index of innerValues array.

Vacancies are indexes that have been removed from Dictionary and "nulled" in array and in case of adding new records will be repopulated with new data instead of appending the data to the end of the array.

the structure it holds is very simple:

```
public unsafe struct DataBytes
{
    public fixed byte bytes[eMemshard.buffer_size];
}
```

Now first byte of this array is actually identifying the type of the record, think of it as a table identifier ins tandard databases. It is actually also an index of table and column definition dictinary that will then be used to translate retrieved data to proxy objects.

Now I am iterating over innerValues struct array and I only need to see if the first byte is larger than zero:

```
    public unsafe void ForEach(Action<DataBytes, byte> act, byte tableIndex)
    {
        cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            int l = innerValues.Length;
            DataBytes iv;

            for (var i = l - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2)
            {
                iv = innerValues[i];

                if (iv.bytes[0] > 0)
                {

                }

                if (i - 1 < 0)
                    continue;

                iv = innerValues[i - 1];

                if (iv.bytes[0] > 0)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
```

This codes takes about 200ms to execute over all 10 million records, BUT when I remove the conditions, the time drops to 0.4 ms.

When I was using standard managed arrays, the times were actually only about 24ms vs 0.x ms. Is using fixed arrays actually a bad idea for this? Also, Is there something that could speed up retrieving the first byte? I want to eliminate and skip records that are in different "table".

Note: I know there are ready solutions to store data in memory, this question is for my own research only, sort of a personal challenge :) but I believe I hit the wall too soon.

Note2: The code is actually in .NETCore but I believe it doesn't make much difference.

**Edit1:**
To help others, here are reasons behind some if the things I did that may make no sense at the first glance:

*Why did I use Dictionary and Array? Why not use only Dictionary?* - Iterating over an array is way faster than enumerating Dictionary and iterating over it's elements.

*Why am I counting to 0 in for loop?* - Comparing to zero has performance benefits over comparing to a very large number.

*Why do I have multiple instructions for each iteration and decrementing by 2?* - Apparently this has something to do with memory contention and I found it to be about 10% faster than single instruction iterations. Maybe somebody can shed more light into this. Also using more than two instructions in an iteration also led to performance increase, but it was negligible. It appears that with more instructions per iteration the performance gain is logarithmic. Two seems like the sweet spot between having a performance gain and having to deal with the remaining entries that didnt fit in the step.

*Why do I have vars declared outside the loop?* - GC likes it :) GC Collections can be eliminated this way.

Comment: i think switching build to x64 Release solved the issue

Comment: Executing multiple instructions in a single loop interation ist faster for two reasons: the first being [Instruction-level parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism) which is implemenented by many modern processors. The second one is less comparisions in the loop header (The `i >= 0` condition has to be checked only half as often as you are incrementing by 2).

Comment: Using pointer arithmetic may be even faster than using fixed arrays, but that would require more unsafe code.